# Android Studio App Change Toolbar Text Colour

Tags: android

This is a screenshot of the toolbar with the text colour as white

[image]

I am new to Android so sorry if this is relatively simple. I want the toolbar to contain a background image as seen in the screenshot. However, I want the text on the toolbar to be more visible such as black (#000). I have tried changing the themes but I lose the ability to have an image as a background. Please can anyone help.

Below is all the code from my activity_main.xml

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_notebook_head"
            android:transitionGroup="false"
            android:backgroundTintMode="screen"
            android:titleTextColor="#000"
           />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: Thanks man, but where does your code go? In the activity_main.xml? Could you add context to the code ?

Comment: in your activity `onCreate` after calling the `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)`

Answer (score -1):

Try to set Background image in Parent Layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
             android:background=".....">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_notebook_head"
        android:transitionGroup="false"
        android:backgroundTintMode="screen"
        android:titleTextColor="#000"
       />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't know what you mean or how to even do that ?

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work unfortunately. The answer above solved it :)